# Will there be a TypeScript template for Universal Apps in VS 2015?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app

I just got VS 2015 setup for development of Windows Universal apps.  I see templates for these kinds of projects under C# and JavaScript, but not under TypeScript.  Should we expect one in the near future?  Perhaps the RTM version of Visual Studio 2015?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official line on this as of 2014 was:

> TypeScript isn’t officially supported for doing Universal App projects, yet.  But you might be able to cobble together some experience, but there will be gaps as we fill them out.  It’s possible that debugging doesn’t quite work correctly for .jsproj, which is what I believe the Universal Apps would use.

The *yet* leads us to the [TypeScript issue for Universal Apps](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/313), which is waiting for a proposal.

So we are still in the *yet* phase officially.